# Windows XP compatible software in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, window, windows-xp, registry, registrykey

I need to hava a clarrification about software installation in windows. I have installed windows XP compatible software (Oxford dictionary - iFinger) in windows 7 ultimate edition (64bit). Once I installed it it works fine without any problem. But after I restart the computer the application wont work any more. It gives the following error.

```
Application Error - Exception in module iFinger.exe . Error creating registry entry.
```

So As it seems software has failed to create a registry entry when installing. My problem is if it fails to create a registry entry at setup time how it runs before i restart the computer? Since it runs erlier is there a way to fix this issue so that it runs after the restart the computer.

Comment: Try running it as administrator.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.  Might want to relocate it to SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

I have resoleved the issue by using the guidence of SLaks. I chnage the compatibility mode to windows vista service pack 2 and set the priviledge level to Administrator. Now it works fine